# TableView like the Contacts app in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, contacts

Hey! I'm working on a contacts app. And I want to have the same type of Tableview with the add button. So when the user adds a new contact it will open a new view which will have the standard buttons and textfields etc. How can I make the app add the same functions to every new view? 
I hope this makes sense!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Same functions to every new view => subclassing. There are some nice objective-c / cocoa tutorials on the net, i suggest reading those before starting out with the UI. You could also use the same XIB file for the same view functions btw, same uitextfields in i etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a broad question - I would suggest to study the code in the [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html).