# TableView like Contact app with photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, contact-form

How can i make a tableview like the contacts app, 
the main problem is how to place correctly the photoHolder like this :

[image]

Comment: Guys, this is not a duplicate of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876037/tableview-like-the-contacts-app-in-the-iphone Plese join me in voing for re-opening. If you feel it is a duplicate then please refer to a true "original". Just some key words that both questions have in common does not make them duplicates to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I give you suggestion that actual `UITableView` should be Start at 'Telephone' and remain cell such like ***'nome', 'Sobrenome' and 'Usuaroi' and also 'photo'*** taken BOX its all are create on custom `UIView`.

After Custom view is created then create your UITableView Wich Have groped style and it all customize by `UILabel` and `UITextField.`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. 
Never tried such a thing.

If it is really a table ...

I'd try a custom cell for the first 3 cells of which I'd try to change the frame. (Move to the right and make it smaller. But code it in a flexible way. No constants. Use offsets from the right and left margin of the table view.

Then I'd try accessing the table view itself, which in the end is not much more than a subclass of UIScrollView and add a UIImageView as subview exactly there where the photo goes.

Give it a try and have fun ...

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:

The first section of the grouped table, the one with the photograph to the left, is not the first section of the table. It is the table header view.

This table header view contains of an UIImage view and a UIcontrainer view. That UIContainer view has a table in it. That scroll view's property is set to not scrollable.

May not be the best idea but looking at the design, it coud work. 
Just ... I am not sure how that top left table reponds to scrolling gestures. Touches (selections etc) should work fine.